# Trying to figure out why page getting redirect for no reason after getting catch error

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I have a login function that basically sends an HTTP request to the node.js server that returns either resolve or reject.

the function works fine when I enter the correct user and password it's working fine
**But** when it's incorrect either username or password I'm getting the reject as expected,

the page instead of staying at the same URL path it changes to this URL: '/' from original: '/sign-up'

Why and how I can make it so it won't redirect to the '/' URL and stay in the original path

**This is the login HTML in the react component**

```
<div className='login-signup-container'>
                     <form
                        className='login-signup-form'
                        onSubmit={(ev) => onLogin(ev)}
                     >
                        <h2 className='underline-style'>Account login</h2>
                        <input
                           type='text'
                           name='username'
                           value={credentials.username}
                           placeholder='Username'
                           onChange={handleChange}
                           required
                           autoFocus
                        />
                        <input
                           type='password'
                           name='password'
                           value={credentials.password}
                           placeholder='Password'
                           onChange={handleChange}
                           required
                        />
                        <button className='btn-login-gradient pointer'>
                           Login
                        </button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
```

**This is the onLogin function in the component**

```
// login function
   async function onLogin(ev = null) {
      if (ev) ev.preventDefault()
      try {
         await login(credentials)
         getCurrUser()
         clearState()
         showSuccessMsg('Login successfully')
      } catch (err) {
         console.log('Failed to login check username and password', err)
         showErrorMsg('Login failed. Please check your username and password.') 
      }
   }
```

**This is the login function which the function above use**

```
export async function login(credentials) {
    try {
        const user = await userService.login(credentials)
        console.log('user', user)
        store.dispatch({
            type: SET_USER,
            user
        })
        socketService.login(user)
        return user
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

**And this is the final function from client that send the HTTP request to server**

```
async function login(userCred) {
   try {
      const user = await httpService.post('auth/login', userCred)
      return saveLocalUser(user)
   } catch (err) {
      throw err
   }
}
```

**This is the function from the node.js server that handle handle the request and its return 401 err to the client as expect**

```
export async function login(req, res) {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    try {
        const user = await authService.login(username, password)
        const loginToken = authService.getLoginToken(user)
        logger.info('User login: ', user)
        res.cookie('loginToken', loginToken, {sameSite: 'None', secure: true})
        res.json(user)
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('Failed to Login ' + err)
        res.status(401).send({ err: 'Failed to Login' })
    }
}
```